# Linking and unlinking subresources in a RESTful way

Tags: web-services, rest

For a school project, I'm designing a RESTful API for managing restaurants and restaurant owners (restaurateurs)

There is a relation between restaurants and restaurateurs.

A restaurant can have one or zero restaurateurs and a restaurateur can have zero or more restaurants.

So far I have the following endpoints:

```
GET    /api/restaurants
POST   /api/restaurants
GET    /api/restaurants/{id}
PUT    /api/restaurants/{id}
DELETE /api/restaurants/{id}
GET    /api/restaurants/{id}/restaurateur

GET    /api/restaurateurs
POST   /api/restaurateurs
GET    /api/restaurateurs/{id}
PUT    /api/restaurateurs/{id}
DELETE /api/restaurateurs/{id}
GET    /api/restaurateurs/{id}/restaurants
GET    /api/restaurateurs/{id}/restaurants/{restaurant-id}
```

Now I want to add the feature to link and unlink restaurants and restaurateurs

What I had in mind is this:

**To link a restaurateur to a restaurant**

```
POST   /api/restaurants/{id}/restaurateur
Body: {"restaurateur_id": 99}
```

And

```
POST   /api/restaurateurs/{id}/restaurants
Body: [99, 88, ...]
```

**To unlink a restaurateur from a restaurant**

```
DELETE /api/restaurants/{id}/restaurateur
```

And

```
DELETE /api/restaurateurs/{id}/restaurants/{restaurant-id}
```

Are those good RESTful solutions, and if not what would you recommend?

What are the best practices for this kind of problem?

Comment: Your URLs look fine and RESTful to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you REST API is for in-house applications, you can use the LINK and UNLINK HTTP verbs.